# Ftp explicit and active with c#

Tags: c#, ftps

i'm trying to develop a solution that permitted to connect to a ftp server through c#.The problem is that when i connect to this ftp server through the public ip.
For example if i connect to it with the private ip the "nat" respond correctly and all is ok.But if i try to connect to this server through a public ip he respond with:you can't connect to this ftp server through a different ip of the ftp.
with filezilla all is ok.(the connection is active and explicit with ssl.
my code:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("IP");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "passw");
request.EnableSsl = true;
request.UsePassive = false;

private bool OnValidateCertificate(object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

any help will be apprecied

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I know his English isn't perfect @DanielA.White but I think it's obvious what he's getting at!

Comment: Sounds more like a network/routing problem than a code problem.

Comment: i'm so sorry for my english.But i think that it's not a network/routing problem because if i try to connect to the server with filezilla with the parameters set to: (transfert active and explicit encrypt) the connection works and i can transfert all that i want.So,can u help me?

Comment: i think the problem is on certificate.but if i tried with the private ip it works if not it doesn't work.Someone know how can i accept a particular certificate,so if i have the file .crt and the key,how can i accept that certificate?